# Why aren't my matplotlib tick labels visible? Same code works for Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, visualization

I am creating a basic figure with 9 subplots, all with shared x and y axes. The default only shows the tick labels for the outermost subplots. I am trying to show the x and y tick labels for all of the inner subplots as well, but nothing I am trying is working on my machine (windows), despite the same code working when I use Jupyter notebooks.

I am using two for loops to loop through all 9 subplots, and then loop through all of the individual x and y labels within those axes, writing label.set_visible(True). This works when using Jupyter notebooks, but does not work when I am writing the code on my machine. See below my versions of Python and Anaconda:
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Current Code:

```
fig, ((ax1,ax2,ax3), (ax4,ax5,ax6), (ax7,ax8,ax9)) = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
linear_data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
ax5.plot(linear_data, '-') # set inside tick labels to visible
for ax in plt.gcf().get_axes():
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels():
        label.set_visible(True)
plt.show()
```

This works with Jupyter notebooks, but on my machine, the tick labels for the inner subplots continue to not be visible.

Jupyter Notebook result:
[image: Jupyter Notebook Result]

Local machine result:
[image: Local machine Python / Anaconda Result]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using in both those cases?

Comment: Jupyter notebooks: 2.0.0, Local machine: 3.0.2 (probably a major cause for the issue, I am clearly new to python/matplotlib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10911), the visibility for ticklabels of shared axes needs to be set via `tick_params` from matplotlib version 2.1 onwards.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

linear_data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
axes[1,1].plot(linear_data, '-')

for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.tick_params(which='both', labelbottom=True, labelleft=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This works, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to show the tick labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Plot figure of subplots with shared axes
fig, ((ax1,ax2,ax3), (ax4,ax5,ax6), (ax7,ax8,ax9)) = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
linear_data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
ax5.plot(linear_data, '-')

# Show tick labels on all subplots
for ax in plt.gcf().get_axes():
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=True)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelleft=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot with labels on subplots]

Note: I am using Python 3.6.6 on my local machine.

Comment: @ImportanceofBeingEarnest Thanks for your edits—I'm not used to having someone improve my answer as I'm in the process of editing it, and didn't notice what you were trying to do until now.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `sharex=True, sharey=True` with `sharex=False, sharey=False`